# About Microservices

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, microservices

I am newly working on MicroServices. I have some queries about Microservices can one seperate microservice of all model class will be created in our project so that we can use that sevices in our project.
   Is there any way to make one seperate file where we could put all modal class and that can we use in different project and in different micro-services. I searched about this, but not found any helpful artical. Please suggest any better alternatives and resources/link. If anyone here could help I will be extremely greatful. . .
Thanks

Comment: it is better to watch this set of videos https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD-mYtebG3X-wOVHINZf_GKknpJs3Oa3O

Comment: watch the 7th video. That will help you surely. Source code also available at https://github.com/krish/microservices-course-on-youtube.git

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it by making a separate microservice project which contains all the hibernate entities and their repositories. After that you can create the dependency of this project in other microservices module POM file  tag.
example:-

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.entities.service</groupId>
<artifactId>HibernateEntities</artifactId>
<version>01.00.00.01</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can import any entities in their respective dao or wherever you want. In my project, we are using the same architecture

Comment: @Slient Killer I understood. Thank you for your valuable comments.